# Регистрация молодого сайта в каталогах

Tags: seo, продвижение

Имеет смысл при начальном продвижении очень молодого сайта регистрироваться в каталогах?

Если, да, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, в каких каталогах лучше (пусть это будут платные/бесплатные).

Comment: Суть регистрации в каталогах для повышения индексации сайта поисковиками. Так как каталоги предназначены для этого полагаю вес сайта для поисковых систем растет. "господа знатоки, исправьте если не прав"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала стоит начать с яндекса и гугла 
https://webmaster.yandex.ru - ссылка на регистрацию в яндексе
https://www.google.com/webmasters/ - ссылка на регистрацию в гугле

Если ваш проект заставляет пользователей оставаться на сайте - это сыграет только в плюс

Comment: добавлю свои пять копеек: счетчик Яндекс.Метрики и\или LiveInternet, опять таки всё зависит от целевой аудитории, после её анализа рекомендую смотреть на топовые площадки в своей сфере